# Deployd dpd "app" - listening on port then goes right to "bye"

Tags: deployd

I had deployd running just fine on my MAC OS, then I let it sit for a couple weeks.
Went back to it, launching the Deployd server with "dpd app_name"

I get the following:

> listening on port 2403
>
> type help for a list of commands
>
> dpd > bye

I've tried to install/reinstall multiple times, it's doing it also on all deployd website examples.
I've tried changing the port, no luck
I've looked for an error log file. Couldn't find any.

I tried to go on Chrome and Safari, same thing: "Connection Refused".

Any idea, anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened to me, just type sudo before dpd.

```
$ sudo dpd
```

If you run:

```
$ DEBUG=* dpd
```

inside the app folder you will probably see the problem is with mongod, and run with sudo solves it.